# MS Dynamics Campaign Response POST : 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am working on MS Dynamics 365, I have taken reference from [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/campaignresponse?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9).

Here when I post the data it gives **500 Internal Server Error**

"GET" works well with same api endpoint.

Do we have any relational parameter that I am missing?

**Post Data**

```
 var payload = new
        {
            subject = "TestSubject",
            statecode=2,
            statuscode=3,
            responsecode=1               
        };
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code. What does your POST request look like? Are you trying to set any readonly properties?

Comment: @DaveClark i have updated my question with post data that i am passing. Can you please help me on the same? Does MS Dynamics have any sample api tester? How can i find which field is required for a **Entity** also i could not find what are the mapping fields to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `regardingobjectid`

I recommend you to use [CRM REST Builder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder), this will help you to generate request, modify & test within CRM. This will show all the required attributes highlighted in Red.

```
var entity = {};
entity.subject = "test";
entity["regardingobjectid_campaign@odata.bind"] = "/campaigns(9CFBD4BD-CD4F-E811-A95A-000D3A1A9407)";
entity.responsecode = 3;

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/campaignresponses", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 204) {
            var uri = this.getResponseHeader("OData-EntityId");
            var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
            var matches = regExp.exec(uri);
            var newEntityId = matches[1];
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(entity));
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, i have hosted into my iis but it gets me **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)** for ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx

Comment: @ParthTrivedi  is your comment related to this question? Sorry I didn’t get it.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi don’t clone the git, instead download the managed solution & import in CRM. https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder/releases

Comment: you are a hero. **regardingobjectid_campaign@odata.bind** worked for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50267093/ms-dynamics-generate-refresh-token-for-oauth can you help me on that?

Comment: Can you give me step how to use **CRMRESTBuilder**. I can not install it. How to install? its give me xml file as managed solution.

Comment: And if i am using solution then it gives me ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx not found in browser console. Need urgent help.

Comment: Can you help me on OAuth part? As i got stuck on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50267093/ms-dynamics-generate-refresh-token-for-oauth